# Copy and rename files in subdirectories based on glob list

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, rename, glob

I am trying to copy and rename all files with the name "mypicture.jpg" in all the subdirectories to "picture.jpg". If I do:

```
import glob
source = glob.glob('**/mypicture.jpg',recursive=True)
print(source)
```

it shows me all mypicture.jpg, but is it possible to copy and rename the .jpg in each directory based on the list?

In the shell I just do:

```
find ./ -name 'mypicture.jpg' -execdir cp -prv '{}' './picture.jpg' ';'
```

and it does what I want.

Just to copy and rename I was able to with  `shutil.copyfile(source, destination)`
but just with the path to the file, so my question is:
How can I pass the filepathes from my list to my `source=`and loop/iterate it then for all files from list? Is that even possible? Or do I have to use another function?

Ok, with pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

dirpath=Path(r'W:/directory')

files=dirpath.rglob("mypicture.jpg")
for path in files:
    print(path)
    shutil.copy(path, path.parent / 'picture.jpg' ,follow_symlinks=True)
```

it works, anything I have to be aware of?

Comment: `glob` will return a list of matching file and you will have to determine a destination path based on the source path for each one before copying it. That could be done with `os.path` or the `pathlib` modules (that latter might be easier). You should attempt to do this and then ask a question with your code in it if you can't figure it or get it work.

Comment: thank you, the pathlib hint helped me to find a working solution!

Comment: That's good news...glad to hear it. After using `os.path` for very long time myself, I started forcing myself to figure out how to do things with `pathlib` instead and have often been impressed with just how easy it is to use and elegant the resulting code — often far superior to the latter for certain types of  problems.

Comment: ...I posted my code above, can you take a look maybe to check if I could make it better, or is it ok as it is?

Comment: Other than the unnecessary `r` prefix on the `Path(r'D:/directory')`, I can't think of anything else you need to be aware of since you say "it works",

Answer (score 0):

```
#import modules
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

#define directory
dirpath=Path('W:/directory')

#search for files path with given name in dir and subdir using rglob
files=dirpath.rglob("mypicture.jpg")

#copy file in same directory with new name to rename
for path in files:
    print(path)
    shutil.copy(path, path.parent / 'picture.jpg' ,follow_symlinks=True)
```